# Wordpress ACF oEmbed field - Embedding Bandcamp content

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, oembed

I've set up with Advanced Custom Field a custom oEmbed field, called *embed.*

And it's displayed in the front end in the simplest way :

```
the_field('embed');
```

Pasting the media url from Youtube, Vimeo or Souncloud works fine and the field displays  the player and it's content correctly.

However embedding Bandcamp content doesn't work.
If i paste the url directly, it just displays the url and doesn't grab the player from Bandcamp.
If i paste the iframe html provided by Bandcamp, it shows the html.

So i'm wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: what does the URL look like from Bandcamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF oEmbed field refers to Wordpress Embeds feature.

You can see the list of supported websites:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/

It's seems that Bandcamp isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Roberto oEmbed doesn't support Bandcamp.

Changing the field type from oEmbed to WYSIWYG did the trick for me and rendered bandcamp iframe, displaying the player as intended.